# Unable to delete Recovery Service Vault

Tags: recovery, azure-backup-vault

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcapk.jpg)Vault deletion error
Recovery Services Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the vault.  : DESKTOP-LHTVUDO. Please ensure all containers have been unregistered from the vault and all private endpoints associated with the vault have been deleted, and retry operation. For more details, see https://aka.ms/AB-AA4ecq5

Performed the below steps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-delete-vault?tabs=portal

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Recovery services vault, then perform the following.

1. Backup items blade under recovery services vault and delete all the items and its associated policies from backup policies blade. Ensure no item is stuck in soft delete. If soft delete is enabled on vault that needs to be disabled.
   For details on Soft Delete, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-security-feature-cloud
2. Under backup infrastructure blade in vault, you need to unregister any servers/agents, storage accounts/file shares etc.,(It most likely this in your case that's blocking you from deleting the vault.